# How to create a polynomial given the degree and the variables

Tags: python, math, polynomials

I want to create a polynomial in Python given the degree and the variables involved. I expect something like this :

```
second_order_polynomial = create_polynomial(['x', 'y'], order=2)
```

where `second_order_polynomial` is a function that computes the second order polynomial given values for `x` and `y`. For me actually the coefficients are not relevant, only the order/power of the variables. So `args` could be all set to 1, but maybe keeping it as parameters would improve the generality of the question :

```
def second_order_polynomial(x, y, *args) -> float:
    return args[0] * x**2 + args[1] y**2 + args[2] * x*y + args[3]
```

Ideally `create_polynomial` would work for arbitrary number of variables and degrees. I would like to avoid using a symbolic toolbox.

This question is similar to this one dealing with Mathematica instead of Python :
[related question from mathematica stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120841/create-a-polynomial-of-a-given-degree)

Comment: What to want to return, a `string` or a number?

Comment: return type of the generated polynomial functions should be a number.

Comment: How would one compute a polynomial w/o the coefficients?  Can you show example(s) of `second_order_polynomial`?

Comment: I phrased myself unfortunately. By irrelevant I mean, all coefficients are set to 1

Answer (score 0):

See this one:

```
def foo(order, li):
    result = 0
    l = len(li)
    if order != len(li):
        raise Exception('Wrong order specified')
    else:
        while(order > 0):
            result += li[l - order] ** order
            order -=1
        return result

print(foo(5, [7, 5, 3, 2, 1])) # 7**5 + 5**4 + 3**3 + 2**2 + 1**1
```

Comment: I think your solution only solves it for one variable.If you have a polynomial involving `x` and `y`, you have to also consider the 'coupling' term `x*y`.

Comment: What type of polynomial do you want. What type of generator function? You should specify that instead. I've provided the answer for a general `n` degree polynomial